# pd.read_csv, when changing separator data type changes?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, separator, txt, x-axis

My dataframe is originally a text file, where the columns are separated by a tab.

I first changed these tabs to spaces by hand (sep=" "), loaded and plotted the data, [my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSoZA.jpg) looked the way it should.
Since I have multiple files to plot, its not really handy to change the separator of each file. That's why I changed the seper<tor to sep="\s+".
Suddenly the x-axis of [my new plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cknE8.jpg) takes every single position value and overlaps them.

Anyone knows why this is happening and how to prevent it?

My first code looked like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

data1500 = pd.read_csv('V026-15.000-0.1.txt', sep = " ", index_col='Position')
plt.plot(data_merged1.ts1500, label="ts 15.00")
```

and the second:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data1500 = pd.read_csv('V025-15.000-0.5.txt', sep = "\s+", index_col='Position')
plt.plot(data_merged2.ts1500, label="ts 15.00")
```

Comment: where do `data_merged1` and `data_merged2` come from?

Comment: I merge various txt files on the index position in one table together. Probably it's an unnecessary step, but the plot should combine the data of multiple txt files.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this to import a tab-delimited file:

```
import re
with open('V026-15.000-0.1.txt.txt') as f:
    data = [re.split('\t',x) for x in f.read().split('\n')]
```

or do this:

```
import csv
with open('data.txt', newline = '') as mytext:                                                                                          
   data = csv.reader(mytext, delimiter='\t')
```

then to plot your data you should do as follow:

Read each line in the file using for loop.

Append required columns into a list.

After reading the whole file, plot the required data

something like this:

```
for row in data:
     x.append(row[0])
     y.append(row[1])
plt.plot(x, y)
```